# Difference between getHeader() and getIntHeader()?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Headers are always Strings. Even the `getIntHeader()` method always takes a String representing the name of the header; so what is the int about?

Comment: -1 For not reading the declaration of methods, but asking here instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getIntHeader()` **accepts the name** of the header and **returns the value** of the header as an int, if it is possible to do so.  So for instance if you had a header "my_header" whose value was equal to the String "307", `getIntHeader("my_header")` would return the int 307, whereas `getHeader("my_header")` would simply return the String.

See the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getIntHeader(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I took the liberty of linking to the Java EE 6 docs; hope that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

`Some headers` represents a **number** instead of string for example

```
Max-Forwards: 5
```

So ,instead of getting `String` and then **parsing** it into an `int`

```
String fowards= request.getHeader("Max-Forwards");
int forward_num=Integer.parseInt(forwards);
```

You can **directly** do

```
int forwards=request.getIntHeader("Max-Forwards");
```